# Removing selected ListView data from a from a SQLite database

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am creating a Business Rota App for my college project using WPF and a SQLite database.
I wanted to delete a record from a database when clicking on the proportionate ListView item. I tried using 'EmployeeList.SelectedItem' to search for the item on my database which always comes as an error since it's an object. I couldn't find online a method to convert the SelectedItem to the text data stored in the listview which I can use to look for the data on my database using 'db.find' and thus remove it.
Am I missing a simple line of code? Thanks

```
<Window x:Class="Business_Rota_Application.StaffMaintenance"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Business_Rota_Application"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="StaffMaintenance" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Column="0" Margin="232,32,232,110" Name="EmployeeList" Grid.RowSpan="3" x:FieldModifier="public">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeID}" Width="100"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="100"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Width="100"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="262,51,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Add_Click" Height="34" Width="76" x:Name="btn_Add"/>
        <Button Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="34" Width="76" Margin="0,51,0,0" x:Name="btn_Update" Click="btn_Update_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="465,51,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="34" Width="76" x:Name="btn_Remove" Click="btn_Remove_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,95,0,22" Grid.Row="2" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
private void btn_Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                using (AppDBContext db = new AppDBContext())
                {
                    var findEmployee = `db.Employees.Find(EmployeeList.SelectedItems);`
                    db.Employees.Remove(findEmployee);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    MessageBox.Show("Data successfully Removed.", "Employee App", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    EmployeeList.Items.Clear();
                    PopulateEmployeeData();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in deleting record", "Employee App", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }         
        }
```

Comment: You have observed that `EmployeeList.SelectedItem` is an object. I'll assume it is an "Employee" Type. So, cast `EmployeeList.SelectedItem` to an `Employee` and use its EmployeeID property to `Find()` the item.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I understand what needs to happen to get my appropriate EmployeeID to search the database. I am fairly new to object oriented programming so I am unsure on how to cast the 'EmployeeList.SelectedItem ' to an 'Employee'. From what I've seen, do I need to make an Employee object?

Comment: You are binding `EmployeeID`, `FirstName` and `LastName` from some Type already. That is what you want to use.

Comment: I'm still not sure on how to code that, would you able to show me an example possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your ListView is bound to a collection of `Employee` (if not, change "Employee" to the Type you are using), you can delete all selected items by casting and accessing the `EmployeeID` property which is used to find the record.

Unrelated, but you might consider creating a DbContext per Form/Window/Page as per [MS recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext).

```
try
{
    using (AppDBContext db = new AppDBContext())
    {
        foreach(var emp in EmployeeList.SelectedItems)
        {
             var empid = ((Employee)emp).EmployeeID;
             var findEmployee = db.Employees.Find(empid);
             db.Employees.Remove(findEmployee);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Data successfully Removed.", "Employee App", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        EmployeeList.Items.Clear();
        PopulateEmployeeData();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error in deleting record", "Employee App", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I am amazed and Inspired over your knowledge and understanding. I feel like my career is doomed before it has even started if I can't even solve such a little problem. Thanks again

Comment: @BenNorthridge like everything else it comes with experience